# Schema level SELECT privilege on all new tables in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica, sql-grant

I am trying to work on a scenario , where one user creates tables in a 'schema', and all such tables should be visible to a specific user/role, **even if** the tables are created in future (after grant SELECT command).

My current flow is as:

USERS: dbadmin, user1, user2
SCHEMA: myschema

```
dbadmin=> GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA  myschema  to  user1;
dbadmin=> GRANT SELECT  ON  ALL  TABLES  IN  SCHEMA  myschema  TO  user2;

dbadmin=> ALTER  SCHEMA  myschema   DEFAULT   INCLUDE  PRIVILEGES;


--  user1  now   creates  table
user1=> CREATE   TABLE  myschema.table1  (id  INT);

-- can user2 see that table
user2=> SELECT  *  FROM  myschema.table1;
--  Permission Denied for table1
```

Any Ideas on how to do this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue from [here](https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/238736/schema-level-select-on-all-new-tables).  Posting here for others.

The only catch in above queries was using **"GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "**
Instead it should be **"GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA"**